# Checking contents of a map in another map in java

Tags: java, maps

I need to write a small snippet of code where I need to check contents of a map (key value) if it exists in another map , remove it from the map

E.g

Map1:

```
1=>obj1
2=>obj21
3=>obj3 
4=>obj4
```

Other map
Map2:

```
10=>obj10
20=>obj20
2=>obj2
30=>obj30
3=>obj3
```

The result of fun (Map1, Map2)
after it executes it has the following ouput

Map2:

```
10=>obj10
2=>obj2
20=>obj20
30=>obj30
```

Is iterating over the smaller map and checking contents (key, value)  is iterating over the smaller map and checking the key and contents in the bigger map the most efficient way to go about it.

Comment: Strange question :) what happens if both maps have the same length ???

Comment: Either I don't really understand you question, or you example has a mistake. Do you want to remove a map entry for map2 if it's key exists as a key in map1 ?

Comment: The result, as I understood, is a new map with all objects from Map2 which aren'T in Map1

Answer (score 2):

```
m1.entrySet().removeAll(m2.entrySet());
```

where m1 is the Map to be modified, and m2 is the map with the mappings that need to be removed from m1.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static <K, V> void fun(Map<K, V> a, Map<K, V> b) {
    Map<K, V> shortestMap = a.size() < b.size() ? a : b;
    Map<K, V> longestMap = a.size() > b.size() ? a : b;

    Set<Entry<K, V>> shortestMapEntries = shortestMap.entrySet();
    Set<Entry<K, V>> longestMapEntries = longestMap.entrySet();

    longestMapEntries.removeAll(shortestMapEntries);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See [java.util.Collection](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html)

```
boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c)
```

Comment: Map has keySet() method that returns a Set. Set extends Collection.

Comment: entrySet() rather than keySet(). He wants to find and remove by complete mappings, not by keys only.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static <K, V> removeDuplicates(Map<K, V> map1, Map<K, V> map2) {
    for (K key : map1.keySet()) {
        V val1 = map1.get(key);
        V val2 = map2.get(key);
        if (val2 != null && val2.equals(val1)
            map2.remove(key);
    }
}
```